# websphere portal session timeout

Tags: websphere-portal

We have an application running on WebSphere Portal with a javascript frontend calling a REST API backend via a servlet. The app is launched via a Portlet.
After the app starts up no further web requests go through the /wps portal context, everything goes through the servlet-based REST API.
The issue we have is that the HttpSession times out even though active requests are being made to the REST API.
Any ideas as to why the HttpSession is disappearing?

Answer (score 0):

do you have security restraints set up on the rest api so it keeps the session id alive?  also the portal session will still die if it is not being accessed evne if your LTPA/JSession id is still valid

Comment: I have security-constraint in web.xml for the REST API. Sounds like I need a way to touch the portal session from the REST API.

Comment: Yep, we often advised people to create a heartbeat(like every minute) or something in javascript to keep the portal session alive

Comment: What you face is part of the J2EE standard. 
J2EE defines that each Application (EAR) gets it's own Session Object. WebSphere manages these as different Objects in the backend and keeps track on the use explicitly by the targeted application.
In your case I assume that your Servlet is not packaged inside of the wps.ear. This means for all subsequent calls WebSphere only keeps track on your additional Servlet. There had been a documentation on the different session timeout options for WebSphere Portal.